# Answer to inserts in an Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, testing, integration-testing, generator

I need to set up a testing environment for an application that will communicate with a 3rd party system.

The 3rd party system I/O is managed like this :

Orders are given by writing data in the INPUT table of the 3rd party system's database, according to which this system will perform physical operations (IRL), then write an answer to the orders in the OUTPUT table of its database (answers like : "performed operation FOO" or "unable to perform operation BAR").

For our testing environment, we have no problem having a live test database instance to replicate the 3rd party systems, but we need some software mechanism to react to the orders inserted in the INPUT table by generating answers into the OUTPUT table, according to various scenarii.

**1st idea** : writing a trigger that will react to inserts on the INPUT table by generating various inserts on the OUTPUT table.

**2nd idea** : writing a custom "mini 3rd party system" that will run on its own server and monitors the test database to be able to answer the INPUT orders like the real system would.

However, both these ideas seem a little too-specific to me... I would be surprised that we are the only ones with such a need, so I think (hope) there are some tools around to simulate this kind of interactions.

Does anybody have some pointers on this kind of tools, or other ideas to address this need in a more elegant way ? (especially considering the ease of creation / maintenance of the different answer scenarii...)

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Advanced Queueing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/aq_intro.htm#i1005550)?

Comment: I didn't know about this technology, so I've just read the intro. I'm unsure if this is relevant to my problem, it seems to be more of a set of APIs to implement messaging between distributed applications, which is not really what I am looking for (since the way the 3rd party system is handling messages in its own database is beyond our concern).

But if you have specific ideas on the way it could be used for what I'm trying to do, I'd be very interested to learn more about it.